# How do you stop a draw commission after reaching a certain number while continuing commission earned after draw limit

Tags: excel

so im very new to excel and I have a problem I need to solve for an internship im applying for. As a heads up I apologize for any confusion, but im happy to answer any questions that I may have left out from the explanation. Regardless I would really appreciate some help!

Question:
If someone starting at a company is allowed a draw of $5,000 a month if they earn a commission of less than $5,000, up to $30,000 within the first 12 months. If they make more than $5,000 in commission, they don't automatically get a draw of $5,000. After the first 12 months, regardless of their commission, they no longer are granted a draw.
How do I automate a draw up until $30k total commission if less than $5k for the first 12 months, and stopping the draw automation after either of those conditions are met while maintaining commission earned indefinitely.

[What I have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzdwF.png)

Again I probably formatted the whole book incorrectly for this. But thats the formula I have made for the calculation so far but I dont know how to make the draw stop after either 12 months or after reaching $30k automatically.

EDIT: heres the formulas I have made so far. Again im just starting to learn this so im probably far off. [Sorry I forgot to add my formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xDKF.png)

Comment: Can you show us the formula(s) you have tried?

Comment: How would you calculate this with a pencil & paper? what is the logic required?Once you have that then you can get Excel to do  it.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I updated it at the bottom with a second image showing the calculations for both of the cells [I]

Comment: @SolarMike Thats kinda my issue currently. I dont know the logical math for this. I'm pretty good with python and id be able to replicate it using python but excel doesnt allow for that kind of depth. Given my resources im kinda at a loss for how to make this possible. Even if I were to do the math on paper. Im still in highschool so I havent been exposed to any math further than calculus and anything I learned from python myself.

Comment: If you can do it in any other language then you must understand the logic.

Comment: @SolarMike Thats my issue though, I dont know Excel for I started a week ago. So while I could figure it out in python, I dont know what to imput into excel to make it do the same thing. I dont understand the translation so even figuring it out in python isnt gonna help me figure it out for excel. If you have any idea for how to solve it I would really appreciate it!

Comment: How would you do it in python?  What logical steps would you take? As @SolarMike writes, if you can do it any language, you must be knowledgeable about the logic.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I’m not proficient in python yet, and i’m not able to get a job where i’m at with it. i’m able to figure things out by making unnecessarily long code, but i don’t know how to implement it into excel since i’m new to both technically. i only have a few months worth of experience with python and excel isn’t the same as python. i’m not at that point yet where i can transition something i do from python to another language, even if it’s only excel. i just need help on how i write the expression in order for it to automate what i need it to do. i don’t know what to do that’s all.